# How can I create a horizontal selector in a form with only html and css?

Tags: html, css, forms, menu

I am trying to create a menu something like this:

```css
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li span {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
ul#menu li span:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><span>HTML</span></li><li>
  <span>CSS</span></li><li>
  <span>JavaScript</span></li><li>
  <span>PHP</span></li>
</ul>
```

But such that this acts similar to a `<select>` field in an html form and so that when one of the elements is clicked, it stays selected (and darkened in the css). How could I do this? (Preferably without javascript because I don't think that it is necessary, but if you must...). I feel like this may have somthing to do with the `form=""` attribute in html, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a combination of radio button inputs, labels, the label's `for` attribute, the adjacent sibling selector, and a **lot** of IDs.

basically, this method sets each of the menu buttons to be a label that has a `for` attribute.  This allows you to associate an input with a label without making the input a descendant of the label.  Then with the adjacent sibling selector (the `+` syntax) and the `:checked` pseudo-class, you can style the label as long as the input is placed immediately before the label (if you can't do immediately before, the `~` selector works too).  Then it's just a matter of hiding the input.

```css
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li label {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
ul#menu li label:hover, ul#menu li input:checked + label {
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
ul#menu li input {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><input type="radio" name="menu-selection" id="html-item"><label for="html-item">HTML</label></li><li>
  <input type="radio" name="menu-selection" id="css-item"><label for="css-item">CSS</label></li><li>
  <input type="radio" name="menu-selection" id="js-item"><label for="js-item">JavaScript</label></li><li>
  <input type="radio" name="menu-selection" id="php-item"><label for="php-item">PHP</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can recreate that effect using checkboxes and labels:

```css
ul#menu li span:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
input:checked +label {
  background-color: #808080;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>

<input id="html" type="radio" name="opt" /><label for="html">HTML</label><input id="css" type="radio" name="opt" /><label for="css">CSS</label><input id="javascript" type="radio" name="opt" /><label for="javascript">JavaScript</label><input id="php" type="radio" name="opt" /><label for="php">PHP</label>
```

Comment: Could you just edit to remove the white space between the elements please?